# IIS SMTP server message id domain

Tags: iis, smtp

I have an issue with `IIS SMTP` Server.

When I send a message the message ID is

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@localhost.localdomain
```

I don't find where change `localhost.localdomain` to the correct domain name.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the message id domain is written during email generation and has nothing to deal with IIS.

The message ID domain must be set in the email creation method.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two ways that the message ID can be set when using the SMTP server that's part of IIS.  If the SMTP server receives a message that already includes a message ID, it leaves it alone.  On the other hand, if the message does not include a message ID, the SMTP server will add it and use the "Local (Default)" domain name for the domain portion of the message ID.  The "Local (Default)" domain name is set when you first create the SMTP virtual server.  It appears at the top of the "Domains" list under the SMTP virtual server in "Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager" and can be changed by renaming it.